# Symfony2 twig template in a template like wrapping content

Tags: php, forms, templates, symfony

I have a question about templating in Symfony2 and wrapping blocks with html etc.

I am wondering if what I am doing is the right way, or if there is another more simple way to achieve my goals.

I have 2 bundles, a template/layout bundle and an entity bundle (which also contains some controllers and views).

In the entity bundle I have a default controller which show some templating, like the left and right pane of the page.

Then I use the `render(controller())` function to load another controller in the same bundle to show the information in the left or the right pane of the page.

In the requested controller I return a table with a list of entities in a container div I extended from the template/layout bundle to "wrap" the table in.

But is this a normal way of doing this? Because only to show a simple page with multple containers I need minimal 2 twig files, 2 controllers, 1 entity.

Here is an example code of what I mean (I know some things are going faster using annotations):

**Acme/EntityBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php**

```
namespace Acme\EntityBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('AcmeEntityBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**Acme/EntityBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig**

```
{% extends "AcmeLayoutBundle:Default:index.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {{ render(controller('AcmeEntityBundle:Entity:list')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        here some other info
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Acme/EntityBundle/Controller/EntityController.php**

```
namespace Acme\EntityBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Acme\EntityBundle\Entity\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class EntityController extends Controller
{
    public function listAction()
    {
        $entities = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AcmeEntityBundle:Entity')
            ->findAll();

        return $this->render('AcmeEntityBundle:Entity:list.html.twig', array('list' => $entities));
    }
}
```

**Acme/EntityBundle/Resources/Entity/list.html.twig**

```
{% extends "AcmeLayoutBundle:templates:containers.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}Just a Title{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>

{% endblock %}
```

As you probably can see, I use 2 controllers. 
 - One as a kind of portal with the basic layout (sidebar, header, content, footer blocks) rendering the second controller
 - And the second controller for the entity itself

And you can see in the twig files I extend the layoutbundle once for the complete layout, and once for a wrapper for the table.

But now again the real question: Is this a correct way to program in symfony2, or is there a better way? Because just to show a list of entities I need to use 4 different files (being universal and not to write anything twice).

[Edit]

As an extension of the question above.

I have a form created with the formBuilder and some parts of the form I need to show on the left pane and some parts on the right pane, but both wrapped in the `container.html.twig` file.

I know of a way to do this with

```
form_start(form)

form_label(form.field1)
form_widget(form.field1)

form_label(form.field2)
form_widget(form.field2)

...

form_end(form)
```

But is this possible at the situation described above? e.g.: put field1 at the left pane and field2 at the right pane. With a submit button at the bottom of the page in maybe a bottom pane or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
But is this a normal way of doing this? Because only to show a simple page with multple containers I need minimal 2 twig files, 2 controllers, 1 entity.
```

Yes, this is a good way of doing. Normal you need another controller to do that because each page of your site will have left and side panes, and you don't want to repeat the same code from a controller to another. avoiding the [Do Not Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) concept, just put you pane's code in a couple of controller/template, and use it anywhere by just a `render` call. [read this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers).

Comment: Ok, so we were going the right way. But how can we save the form generated by a `render(controller())` command? Because I think the request isn't passed through the controller by this way.

Comment: your `render` command will just call the given controller and render it in your current page using the template you defined in that controller. So if you have a form in one of your side panes, add the `action` attribute in the form tag in twig, and give the `route` of the controller you created for that purpose. Notice that your side panes are like a simple symfony page, a mixture of Route, Controller and Template.

Comment: That is a problem because there isn't a route to the controller. I would want to create all my controllers like widgets to use them later on (saving and redirecting to the page you came from). But I think I got it working by passing a `with { request: app.request }` to the `render(controller())` method. 
One thing I still need to know is if I can use this method also with an AJAX save. Because the output of the controller is always a template.

Comment: happy you have found a solution. for the Ajax issue, be more clear !

Comment: I have done some stuff a different way. We have created a new controller method which can handle ajax calls. When we save the data, first the default controller checks if the request is an AJAX request, if so the custom method will be called and the default method (by returning a template) will be 'terminated'.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed both by using `render(controller())` helpers in the template. 
And for the AJAX we created a complete new method, when the request is an AJAX request this method will be called and the default method (by returning a template) will be 'terminated'.